# PHP, how can I produce a list of unique numbers?

Tags: php

I have some numbers which will be part of an sql query, like this...

```
152258, 152258, 152258, 152258, 152261, 152261, 152261, 152261, 152261, 152270, 
152270, 152270, 152287, 152287, 152287, 152287
```

My query is quite complex and the list is quite long and I need to produce a unique list of numbers, can I do this with a regex?

If not how ?

Comment: Can you filter the list of numbers *before* putting them in the SQL?

Comment: Do you want to generate unique numbers or do you want to filter out the repeats?

Comment: please explain further, are these numbers already generated, do you need to put them into a database, are there any factors such as min and max to take into consideration, should they be unique in the DB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can make your string have unique numbers:
http://codepad.org/cziNtZOS

```
<?php

$myString = "152258,152258,152258,152258,152261,152261,152261,152261,152261,152270,152270,152270,152287,152287,152287,152287";
$array = explode(",",$myString);
$unique = array_unique ( $array  );
$myUniqueString = implode(",",$unique);
echo $myUniqueString ;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write a function for you, turns out PHP has one already: [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

**Edit**: in any case, this is one of the alternative ways of doing it:

```
function uniquify_array($a)
{
    $b = array();  // I wish I could write just $b = {};
    foreach ($a as $i)
        $b[$i] = $i;
    return $b;
}
```

Note that this function works only with values, whereas the built-in `array_unique()` preserves the keys in the original array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a range of numbers use PHP's range() method

If you want a unique list of numbers, you can use PHP's rand() method

range() : http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

rand() : http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

**EDIT**
And as @RobertPitt points out, uniqid can be used for generating IDs as well : http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 1):

Generate some set of numbers and then just use `array_unique` function

`$nums = array();`

`for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {`
`$nums[] = rand() * 10000;`

`$nums = array_unique($nums);`

`}`

Sultan

Answer (score 0):

USE  `RANGE()`

[REFERENCE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.